How to get download and upload speed of the devices internet connection in React Native Expo based app?
I need to implement getting download and upload speed of the current network in React Native + Expo based app.
We need to be able to get realtime information about the network, we need only the download and upload
So have any of you guys came across the same feature to implement and how did you complete it?
I've come across few libraries but none of them worked.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@speedchecker/react-native-plugin

have same errors as guy in the Issues of the github repo

